# How can I prove using the chain rule for function $u(x,y)$ s.t. $f(s,t) = u(e^{s+t} , e^{s-t})$ that $f_{ts}= 0$ iff $x^2u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}=yu_y-xu_x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-writing, chain-rule

I am given a function $u(x,y)$ such that $f(s,t) = u(e^{s+t} , e^{s-t})$

How can I prove that

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s \partial t} = 0 \iff
x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} - 
y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 
y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$

I tried writing the derivative of $f$ according to $t$ and deriving the result according to $s$ but I did not get to the proof.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$

The $s$ derivative of that gave me :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial s\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial s\partial t}$$

I would really appreciate any help in this, thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: Do you mean $e^s +t$ or $e^{s+t}$?

Comment: The second option, e^(S+t)

Answer (score 1):

You mean $$f(s,t)=u(x,y), \text{ where }x=e^{},y=e^{s-t}$$
I'll use the notation $$u_1=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},u_2=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},u_{12}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}) etc.$$Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$ 
$$=u_1x+u_2{\partial y}y$$ Then 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s})=(u_{11}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+u_{12}\frac{\partial y}{\partial}t)x+u_1\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$$ 
$$+(u_{21}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+u_{22}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})y+u_2\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$
$$=(u_{11}x-u_{12}y)x+u_1x+(u_{21}x-u_{22}y)y-u_2y $$
$$=u_{11}x^2+u_1x-u_{22}y^2-u_2y$$ Thus $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s})=0$$ iff
$$u_{11}x^2-u_{22}y^2=u_2y-u_1x.$$

Comment: The question refers to d^2f/dsdt=0 and not twice according to t the way you did it. Is it the same? And x=e^s+t?

Comment: @ topzeramail:I fixed the two places where I mistakenly wrote t when I meant s.